# RF Amplifier GND/VCC Connector

Tags: connector, cables, packages

Is there a standard connector used to connect the ground/supply pins on an RF amplifier to a power supply? For example, many RF amplifiers (also attenuators) I've seen use two pins like this:

[image: product]

[image: datasheet]

But I have no idea if there's a standard name/mating connector for them. The reason I ask if that I've accidentally shorted an amplifier using alligator clips, and am wondering if there's an alternative option to limit the amount of exposed metal.

Comment: I thought the idea was to solder wires to them.

Comment: That's not a connector, it's a point to solder wires onto. Hint, fix the wire mechanically to heatsink with a nylon cable tie, as the soldered joints to those pins will quickly break through flexing.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you both!

Comment: See https://www.minicircuits.com/app/AN40-010.pdf for specification on how to connect to these.